# Jhipster Deploy to Heroku Returning a 404

Tags: heroku, jhipster

I've just started with Jhipster and have built a standard app (Maven, Postgres, Grunt, Sass, Java 8). It works fine in Dev but when I run the `yo jhipster:heroku` command, and then cd to `deploy/heroku` and run `heroku open` the browser responds with a 404. 
The Postgres database looks fine on Heroku (no lock tables). Subsequent runs of `grunt deployHeroku` and `git push heroku master` don't solve the problem.
The heroku logs:

```
2015-04-26T13:29:36.053325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c7f77c65-688f-45ac-90f4-aac54d0cea95 fwd="185.51.75.249" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=50ms status=404 bytes=4224
2015-04-26T13:29:36.331877+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=84eb4f79-9eda-4517-a60d-3fd25f2e6176 fwd="185.51.75.249" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=5647
```

What's interesting is that the favicon and the custom 404 page (I modified it to test this) itself are working correctly. However all of the routes result in a 404. The Heroku logs indicate the app is running.

**Update**
I did a maven build locally using the prod configuration and ran it:

```
mvn -Pprod package
mvn spring-boot:run
grunt serve
```

All worked fine on my dev machine. Also, deployment to Cloud Front is working.

Any ideas, or more info I can provide?

Thanks.

Comment: Is t404 custom 404 page a heroku page or part of your java application?

Comment: @Robert - it's part of my app. It's an error page served from a server-side template in `resources/templates/error.html`.

Comment: I take back the port suggestion then. I'll leave it up though.

Comment: Can you provide your full startup log on Heroku? It's possible it's not starting up in 60 seconds or less.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem! any workaround?

Comment: Facing same problem. Can anyone please suggest any workaround? I have also tried this solution-
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2956

But still no luck

Answer (score 0):

This should be issue with running frontend of jhipster webapp, that I did not resolve yet, but at least you can check whether your spring boot backend is alive:
`https://PROJECT_NAME.herokuapp.com/management/info`

I am running jhipster with -Pdev profile so far on heroku.